# How can I determine surface area of an ellipsoid cut at top and bottom?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, area

I have a general ellipsoid like
 $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} +\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$
 which is cut at top and bottom as say $zTopCut$ and $zBottomCut$. How can I determine surface area on the curved surface of the ellipsoid? I need to implement in coding.

My idea was to divide $z$-axis into several ellipse shells. Then determine $a$ and $b$ for the mentioned $z$. Then find the surface area as 
$$4 \int_0^a {\sqrt{\left({ 1 +\frac{dy}{dx}}\right)}^2}dx.$$
But the result is not OK. I am confused.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: I am a little confused by your formatting---can you please check to make sure that my edits are correct?

Comment: The issue with integrating w.r.t. z is that the "slices" will have different widths at different locations depending on the angle the surface makes with  the z-axis. It might be better to find a parameterization of the ellipsoid's surface and integrate in that coordinate system.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, yes, OK. Thanks.  Actually, I wanted to put "ellipsoid" and "surface area" tags, which I could not as those were not available.

Comment: @Kajelad, I tried your idea. But I had some fundamental ignorance for which it did not work out well using $d\beta$ and $d\lambda$ .